# "launch:program does not exist" in VS Code Using Linux

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNAhT.png)
I am trying to open project c++ on vs code and launch it
but I get an error " launch:program XXX does not exist"

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode":"gdb"
    }
]
}
```

notr: I'm using Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: Well, you didn't enter the program name there, right where it says you should do it

Comment: I recommend you read e.g. [this C++ using GCC on Linux with VSCode tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux). Are all configuration files setup properly? Does the project build correctly?

Comment: The launch config in your screenshot is different than what you posted in the question. Please fix that

Comment: And you should also read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference - because putting `${fileDirName}` as the `"program"` makes no sense

Comment: the screenshot is a different because I make update on the code and added the screenshot after updated   , I don't know what should I put instead of  "program":"${fileDirName}"  to be generated